# Unable to see files Android phone Galaxy S5 connected via usb

Tags: usb, files, samsung

Does anybody know how to make files from the phone to show on my computer. 14.04 
I need to transfer photos and videos to computer. 
It was working fine yesterday.
Here is the screenshot, as you can see it shows "SAMS". for the samsung phone.

[image: Phone Android Galaxy Samsung S5]

Comment: Have you tried rebooting both your computer and the phone?

Comment: Yup, I actually thought it would fix it and is the first thing I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your mobile phone locked? (ie with a password, fingerprint, etc)

If your phone is locked, you need to:

- connect the phone via USB to you computer.
- Unlock your phone (enter password, apply fingerprint) to access the data.

Basically if your phone is locked, your computer can't read the storage UNTIL you unlock your phone, giving access to the computer.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/users/369404/yonsy-solis Thank you very much, It worked!!!! So little details huh!